# vm_flags vs vm_page_prot

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am working with linux kernel 2.6.38 and have a question about two fields of a `vm_area_struct`, `vm_flags` and `vm_page_prot`. If I mmap private anonymous memory to be readable and writable, and then I print out the two fields of the created vm_area_struct, I see that the low 8 bits of `vm_flags` are 0x73 and the low 8 bits of `vm_page_prot` are 0x25. I am running x86 32-bit, and my constants are

```
VM_READ=0x01
VM_WRITE=0x02
VM_EXEC=0x04
```

Thus, it appears my vm_flags says the memory is read/write but the vm_page_prot says it is only readable (the executable flag is meaningless on x86). My understanding is that `vm_page_prot` is supposed to reflect the protection of page table entries of pages in the VM region. As I go onto read/write memory in the mmaped area in userspace, the page faulting mechanism work correctly, setting the PTE's of the appropriate pages. Some pages (if I only read from them) are mapped to the special zero page frame with the PTE set to *read only* while other pages that are written to have the PTE set to *read/write*. This is expected behavior...in fact, from mm/memory.c:

```
static int do_anonymous_page(struct mm_struct *mm, struct vm_area_struct *vma,
    unsigned long address, pte_t *page_table, pmd_t *pmd,
    unsigned int flags)
{
    ...
    entry = pte_mkspecial(pfn_pte(my_zero_pfn(address), vma->vm_page_prot));
    ...
}
```

My question is what determines `vm_page_prot`. My guess is that `vm_page_prot` is somehow a most restrictive combination (intersection) of all page permissions within the VM region, whereas `vm_flags` actually describes the true intentions of how the memory should act.

Does anyone have any good articles on what the exact purposes/differences of the two fields are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice the C types of these two fields. `vm_page_prot`'s type is `pgprot_t`, which is a **arch** level data type, meaning it can be applied directly to the PTEs of the underlying architecture. On x86 32-bit, this field stores the content of the proper protection bits for the PTEs of the VMA. `vm_flags`, on the contrary, is an **arch-independent** field, whose bits are defined in `linux/mm.h`. There are numerous `VM_`* bits, and they extend heavily over just the simple flags of READ, WRITE, and EXEC.

So it looks to me that `vm_page_prot` is a form of a cached conversion from `vm_flags`, which stores the proper protection bits for the underlying architecture. Notice that in many areas where a PTE is formed in the VMA, `pgprot_t` is being used almost directly.

Comment: But clearly vm_page_prot doesn't (in my example) store proper protection bits for the region of the underlying architecture, since my vm_flags had the write bit set, but vm_page_prot for x86 did not have the write bit set.

Comment: Further about the purpose of vm_page_prot other than being the cache to the initial PTE protection - notice the conversion `vma->vm_page_prot = vm_get_page_prot(vma->vm_flags);` that happens in several places in the code and the special cases that assign to `vm_page_prot` a slightly different value using some variation on that assignment, for example in `mm/mprotect.c`. I hope this was helpful.